# Android Studio Emulator makes Windows 10 crash

Tags: android-studio, flutter, android-emulator, emulation, mcafee

It was all working fine until this morning...

Then I loaded McAfee onto my Windows 10 laptop because the free trial period was up.  While doing this I noticed Windows 10 did some updates on a restart.

After that, Android Studio wouldn't run like it had before (earlier this morning), and in particular running the emulator made the system 'blue screen' crash.  So I completely removed McAfee.  Now the Emulator will start up OK, but the same crash happens when Android Studio tries to load my app (Flutter) into it.

(Fortunately Android Studio will still build an APK for my phone, so not everything is lost.)

What's going on??  Have I (or McAfee) mucked up some security setting on the PC, so the Emulator can't talk to Android Studio?  Loads of disc space so it's not that ...  I'm a bit stuck for what to try next ...

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Click on the AVD icon, right click on the installed AVD, click Wipe Data then start it.

Comment: Just tried what you suggested.  Seemed to work slightly better, but then the Emulator kept closing down before my app loaded.  Eventually after several tries it got to the point where my app loaded and ran on the emulator.  But then it crashed again (blue screen) - HYPERVISOR ERROR.

Comment: You need to enable hyper v for your emulator to work properly.

Comment: New day - thanks for the feedback guys.  Found 'programs and features' and Windows Hypervisor was already on. Turned it off and on again, and I also turned on 'Virtual Machine Platform' seemed it might be relevant.  Good news - no blue screen crashes this morning. Bad news - Emulator ran my app but then just stopped.  Happened 4 times, with same error message in the event log: WHPX: Unexpected VP exit code 5.